# Mac frequently restarting with no space error

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, macos-monterey

I have intel powered macbook pro. I use it ios app development. My laptops started giving trouble and randomly restarting since i updated to "Monterey".

[image]

Comment: How full is your ssd?

Comment: 50gb free space

Comment: Some Googling seems to imply this is a software bug which Apple is ignoring :(  The error likely relates to the graphics driver.

Comment: Try a manual backup to Time Machine - that would at least flush the local backups, in case it really is an out of space error.